# Introducing an object for the time in an "or" clause: a/an or said?

Tags: claim-construction

Which is correct?

> ... comprising an A, or a device which may be characterized as **an** A, ...

or

> ... comprising an A, or a device which may be characterized as **said** A, ...

**Update:** Think about it: normal people understand the first statement in everyday speech, for example:

> Yes, Mr. Loan Officer, I do drive an automobile, or a vehicle which may be characterized as an automobile. (A golf cart in Palm Desert that is road-worthy comes to mind.)

The above is obvious, and I can repeat "an automobile" safely.

Now, given the MPEP and their "a" --> "the/said" antecedent rule, I'm saying "an A" twice in the first statement of my question.

Which is correct for a patent with said grammar recited at my own peril with regard to "an" or "said"? I feel the first statement is fine because I'm stating, "An A, or a device ...". The purpose of this question is to confirm with the community.

Comment: Not  necessarily agreeing with your basic construction but ask yourself if the second mention of A is referring to the first mention. Imagine A was a gear box.

Comment: Is there a difference between an A and something like an A? (Characterized as an A). Can a reader deduce an understanding of that by reading the spec? How like an A but not an A are we taking about. Seems indefinite unless the spec teaches it.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite If I asked this on the English SE site, I would overwhelmingly get "the first one" as an answer. I ask here because of the MPEP guideline on only introducing a term once, then using _the/said_ a second time. While the claim is closer to "comprising an A or a device" (which are unique terms), I am double-checking with experts here in my question.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite This question is a condensed precursor to my other question about "processor". So, I might claim, "comprising **a** processor, or a device which may be characterized as **a** processor", to hedge my term in the eyes of a judge and jury (even though my spec is very detailed).

Comment: The question really needs more clarification. Adding the clarification to the question is better than using comments.

Comment: @EricS Okay, I've added more detail to the question, and I suspect I have my own answer. Thanks for your interest in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the second mention of A isn't the same A as the first mention of A so it is not "said A". Patent grammar is English grammar but more precise.